# Android SIP listener onCallEnded delay when call has ended

Tags: android, voip, sip

I am using android built in [SIP API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/package-summary.html). ([Example code](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SipDemo/index.html)) I need to do close the session when call has ended (SipAudioCall.endCall() and SipAudioCall.close()).

**Problem**: when user on the other side hangs up, it takes 0-60 seconds until the listener in

```
SipAudioCall.Listener.onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call)
```

is triggered. Also call.isInCall() takes aproximatly the same amount of time to change. I need to close the session/call in order to make another call. At the moment when the user on the other end hangs up first, I have to wait up to 60 sec to make another call.

Why does it take so much time to trigger onCallEnded and is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the same code but getting no time delay.
I have a audiocall listner on both makecall and take call and when i disconnect a call, i simple call audioCall.endCall() on audioCall object returned by takecall().

If still need some help please comment and i need to ask how are you implementing call reject feature.

Thanks

Comment: I haven't implemented reject functionality (my app is in house use only for making calls). I think the delay is probably my network specific.